Why can't I have 6 items in a row with 6 columns?
I have a form with the layout Vertical and the number of columns 6. I also have a lot of DataCards. However, there are only 4 DataCards in each row instead of 6. The minimum width of the form is also longer than 6 DataCards. I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I have changed the size of the fields, reset the number of columns several times
